# PHPSeclib Unable to Download File even tho it exist

Tags: php, phpseclib

I can't seem to understand why the file is not downloading while it really exists.
Here's my code.

**fileDownload.PHP**

```
use \Logic\FTPConnection;
$ftpPath= 'path/to/file.txt';
$localPath = 'temp/file.txt';

$objFTPCon = new FTPConnection(FTP_HOST, FTP_USER, FTP_PASS);
$objFTPCon->openConnection();
$exist = $objFTPCon->isFileExist($ftpPath); // this returns as true
$objFTPCon->downloadFile($localPath , $ftpPath); // not downloading
```

**FTPConnection.php**

```
public function openConnection() // DONE
{
    if (!$this->ftpOpen) {
        
        $this->objConn = new SFTP($this->strHost);
        if ($this->objConn === false) {
            throw new \Exception('Unable to connect to SFTP server.');
        }

        if (!$this->objConn->login($this->strUser, $this->rsa)) {
            throw new \Exception('Unable to login to SFTP server.');
        }
        $this->ftpOpen = true;
    }
}

public function isFileExist($p_strFile) 
{
    $this->openConnection();
    $strStandardizedPath = $this->standardizePath($p_strFile);

    $blnFileExist = false;
    
    $strFile = substr($strStandardizedPath, strrpos($strStandardizedPath, '/') + 1);
    $strPath = substr($strStandardizedPath, 0, strrpos($strStandardizedPath, '/'));
    
    if ($this->isPathExist($strPath)) {
        $arrFileList = $this->objConn->nlist($strPath);
        if ($arrFileList) {
            if (in_array($strFile, $arrFileList)) {
                $blnFileExist = true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $blnFileExist;
}

public function downloadFile($p_strTargetFile, $p_strSourceFile)
{
    $this->openConnection();
    // $this->objConn->get($p_strTargetFile, $p_strSourceFile, FTP_BINARY);
    if (!$this->objConn->get($p_strTargetFile, $p_strSourceFile, FTP_BINARY)) {
        throw new \Exception('Unable to download file.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain "file is not downloading"... is there any error message? what is the observation?

Comment: @HonkderHase technically the file isn't saving in the local repository / app server repository ..

Comment: "is not saving in the local repository" - so, the fetch from SFTP did work actually, but the local Filesystem doesn't save it? tbh, there should be some error messages somewhere...

Comment: `$this->objConn->get($p_strTargetFile, $p_strSourceFile, FTP_BINARY))` - the third parameter doesn't do what you think it does. It denotes the _offset_ as discussed at https://phpseclib.com/docs/sftp#downloading-files. In https://php.net/ftp-get the third parameter is for `$mode` but phpseclib isn't the ftp extension

Comment: Anyway, can you post the SSH2 logs? You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2)` at the top of the file and `echo $this->objConn->getLog()` after the failed download attempt. Like maybe it's a permissions issue or some such. The logs should elucidate

Answer (score 2):

It appears that my parameters for get() is wrong.
I just swapped it and it works:

so instead of:

```
$this->objConn->get($p_strTargetFile, $p_strSourceFile, FTP_BINARY);
```

i used:

```
$this->objConn->get($p_strSourceFile, $p_strTargetFile);
```